# The relation between matrix size and closure

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm working on a problem and trying to determine, whether there is a relation between a matrix size (number of rows and columns), and closure of the matrix (whether it is closed under addition and multiplication).

It's a part of the problem I am solving and I don't have any ideas. Can you help?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "closure of the matrix" ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Sum of two matrices is still a matrix, multiplication of two matrices is still a matrix.

Comment: Ok, how do you define the sum and the multiplication of two matrices ? (There should be conditions on the size for your definition to be valid)